# CPU load of python serial read

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, serial-port, pyserial

I have an application where I need to read from a serial port in a thread in Python. Since it is placed in a thread I though I could use:

```
timeout = None
```

And using the following code in the thread:

```
# Setup
ser = serial.Serial(port, 38400, timeout = None)

# Loop
data = ser.read(2)
if data[0] == 2:
    data += ser.read(data[1]-2) # Expected length of message
    return data
else: # Handle error message
```

However when I compare it to the frequency of the other threads I get an increased frequency of almost 200% by instead using:

```
# Setup
ser = serial.Serial(port, 38400, timeout = 0)

# Loop
data = ser.read(1)
if data and data[0] == 2:
    while len(data) < 2:
        data += ser.read(1)
    while len(data) < data[1]:
        data += ser.read(1)
    return data
else: # Handle error message
```

And further more, during simulation the data is collected and then "replayed" using a socket instead, and when using the socket I get an even better result, leading me to belive that I should be able to increase the overall frequency of the application even in real time. However I can not find any relevent discussions about the time complexity of serial read in Python.

Edit:

After further tinkering and testing I still can not figure out the best way to read the serial port... Is there any "correct" answer to what the best way to read a serial port in regards to time complexity is?

// Jakob

Comment: you are sure end of Data is reliable ? I always wait for a special character as there can be always a time out during serial comminication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not quite enough information to know exactly what is going on, but it appears that you are trying to receive messages that take one of the following forms:

- A "Data" message, which looks like: `| 2 | Length | d1 | d2 | ... | dN |`
- Some error indication...which you don't mention, but perhaps is just a single byte that is not 2?

In your first implementation, the line `data = ser.read(2)` will "wait forever until at least two bytes are received". But if a single 1-byte message is sent, then the code will keep waiting forever until another message is received.

While there is no "right" way to read from a serial port, you might want to try separating the byte receiving and the message parsing.

For example, you might have something like this:

```
from collections import deque


def receive_bytes(ser, buffer):
    """Read bytes from serial port and append them to the buffer"""
    data = ser.read(1)
    while data:
        buffer.append(data[0])
        data = ser.read(1)


def consume_messages(buffer):
    """Consume available messages from the buffer destructively"""

    # This loop uses the first byte as the key for what
    # message should be in the buffer. We only consume
    # a message from the buffer when it is present in
    # its entirety (i.e. we only read a data mesage once
    # all the bytes are present).
    messages = []
    while len(buffer) > 0:
        # Check if we have a data message
        if buffer[0] == 2 and len(buffer) > 1:
            data_message_len = buffer[1]
            if len(buffer) - 2 > data_message_len:
                # looks like enough info for a data message
                buffer.popleft()  # the 2 byte
                buffer.popleft()  # the length byte
                data_message = [
                    buffer.popleft() for _ in range(data_message_len)
                ]
                messages.append(data_message)

        # Check if we have a "1" message
        elif buffer[0] == 1:
            messages.append(buffer.popleft())

        else:
            # looks like the first byte is something we don't
            # know about...likely a synchronization error, so just
            # drop it
            buffer.popleft()

    return messages


def handle_messages(messages):
    for m in messages:
        print(m)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # setup
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 38400, timeout=0)
    buf = deque()

    # loop
    while True:
        receive_bytes(ser, buf)
        messages = consume_messages(buf)
        handle_messages(messages)
```

FWIW, I don't think that time complexity is relevant here. The blocking nature of the original code and the interaction between your application code, the serial library, and the underlying OS are all larger factors than the time complexity.

Basically...your computer is waaaay faster than the hardware controlling the serial port, so having a block-and-wait approach will generally waste more computation time than checking with no timeout - even if you are checking thousands/millions of times between bytes.

Comment: I had the same thought about the complexity however during simulations I use and internal socket instead of a serial port and the update frequency of the application is much higher when using the internal socket. And since most of the application is CPU bound it would indicate that there is some load on the CPU from reading the serial port.

Comment: Good point I guess, but it might be that it is faster for the underlying OS to check its networking stack to see if 2 bytes are available than it is to check your serial hardware (which is probably a serial port emulator over USB right?). It would be interesting if you find a difference between the blocking checks if you ask for only 1 byte instead.

Comment: I am using a usb serial port. The application is a real time navigation system for an autonomous fork-lift and the sensor sending data over the serial port is the wheel encoder

Answer (score 0):

Try force the serial port to wait on I/O ser.read(ser.inWaiting() + 32)

I saw that serial_port.read(serial_port.in_waiting) can read very fast and it avoids the problem with accumulation of bytes in buffer

And if you are on Python3 then ser.read() returns bytes, so any comparison will be false. Debug : data[0] == 2 would need to be data[0:1] == b'2'

Play with:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port, 38400)
while(True):        
    print('ser_is_open')
    ser.read(ser.in_waiting() + 32)                   
    print('ser_in_waiting')
```

Comment: The serial I/O is in this case a wheel encoder and it seems as though it would be a bad idea to read multiple messages at ones if they are stacked in the buffer. I am using python 3 and the `data[0] == 2` has worked out great...